# Office URI Schemes Security Considerations

Tags: ms-word, authorization, webdav

We use the `ms-word:ofe|u|https://www.example.com/document.docx` scheme in our application to be able to edit documents. [The Office URI Scheme documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes) contains a "Security Considerations" section for all schemes. These sections describe the need to guard against opening documents from untrusted remote systems but do not contain information on how to do this.

We have tried enabling basic AUTH to secure documents, which is probably not the best approach since credentials will constantly be moving over the network, but this is just for testing to understand how it works. When we try to open a protected document in Word, we see a form asking for credentials.

[form asking for credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TIN5.png)

However, the entered credentials do not affect the application request, and the request still does not contain an authorization header.

How to properly implement document protection and how make it so that Word can log in in the appropriate way? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is your application called? I can give you an answer I just want to check before I do so